# On-Premise Azure DevOps Server 2019: Backup Retained Builds' Artifacts

Tags: c#, tfsbuild, agent, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-server-2019

#### Background

I am currently migrating my on-premise `Team Foundation Server 2015 (Update 4)` to `Azure DevOps Server 2019`.

#### What I used so far

I have built a C# console application that scanned through the builds machine in the previous version (TFS 2015), checking for the `KeepForever` tag on each build. In case it existed- backing up the contents of the build directory to my remote backup server. Otherwise, if the defined retained period passed, it will clean the agent's directory. I was able to do so using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll` and `TfsTeamProjectCollection` class specifically to do just that:

```
IBuildDefinition[] BuildDefinitionArray = Builder.BuildsServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(TeamProjectName);

foreach (var BuildDefinition in BuildDefinitionArray)
{
    // Create CreateBuildDetailSpec without InformationTypes to speed up (A LOT) the function time
    var BuildDetailSpectator = Builder.BuildsServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(TeamProjectName, BuildDefinition.Name);
    BuildDetailSpectator.InformationTypes = null;

    // Find all Builds that answer the to the `BuildDetailSpectator`
    IBuildQueryResult BuildQueryResult = Builder.BuildsServer.QueryBuilds(BuildDetailSpectator);

    for each (var BuildResult in BuildQueryResult.Builds)
    {
        // Get build's files full path (drop location)
        string BuildDropLocationPath = BuildResult.DropLocation;

        // Check whether the build is RETAINED
        if (BuildResult.KeepForever)
        { ... }
    }
}
```

#### The problem I am currently facing

It seems like this solution is now old-fashioned and pretty much broken while using a newer version of ADO and `.NET Core`. Searching through the internet, I have found some tools such as [Post Build Cleanup](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.PostBuildCleanup) and [downloading agent's artifacts using Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). They all seem to provide a portion of the entire solution, but nothing seems to work as I need it to be- meaning: the contents of builds flagged as "Retain indefinitely" will be moved to another location (a backup server).

I should mention that Azure DevOps Server 2019 uses the `v2.153.1` agent.

**EDIT:** I must say the scope\language used for the solution does not matter to me as long as it will allow me to access the DevOps Server and backup all of the different "keep forever" builds' artifacts.

Comment: Hi, you have migrated you TFS version to Azure DevOps Server 2019 and now you want to backup the retain pipeline to another location in the Azure DevOps Server 2019, right?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Not in the Azure DevOps Server 2019 (as far as I know, this does not make sense to backup ADO files inside the ADO itself), but to any remote server in which I'll have a backup file for those retained build.

Comment: Hi @Erelephant, as I know, it will save the retain build in the Azure DevOps Database, the tab name is `db.xxx`, If have any misunderstanding, could you re-describe more details about scenario?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT I'll try to rephrase: I'm using the `Publish Build Artifacts` task to copy the made artifacts into a local machine. The data stored inside the DB is just a 'shell', which gives me some info about the build, such as where the artifacts are stored (e.g., in my provided code, I could access it using `BuildResult.DropLocation`). I want to do the same, but it seems like the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll` is not supported anymore.

Comment: Hi, Sorry to reply you so late. "I'm using the Publish Build Artifacts task to copy the made artifacts into a local machine." It just save the Artifacts instead of retain build history